# Within a radio-group, how to add and remove class names at radio button parents when checking/unchecking takes place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, event-handling, radio-group

I am trying to add a class to the radio button parent element when checked.
The problem is, the class doesn't seem to delete when using `removeClass`. I can still see the red background when the checkbox is unchecked.

This is what I came up with so far ...

```js
$('input:radio').change(function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {

    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #fff5f5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey"
         checked>
  <label for="huey">Huey</label>
</div>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
  <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
</div>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  <label for="louie">Louie</label>
</div>
```

How do I need to change my code in order to achieve the correct  behavior?

Comment: That's because the change event only fires for the radio button is getting checked, but not for the one that is getting un-checked by that same action. (Putting a `console.log($(this).val())` as first thing into your handler function, would have shown you that.) So you will either need to remember the previous selection in a variable, or remove the class from _all_ these parent divs first, and then only add it for that of the radio button whose transition into the checked state you are currently handling.

Comment: Someday, you'll be able to do this just with CSS via the [`:has` pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational). But not today. :-(

Comment: @theovogg CBroe proposed _two_ solutions.

Comment: @theovogg ... From all the provided solutions are there any questions left?

Comment: @theovogg ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

No need to check else part in the `is(':checked')` condition.

> On click of radio button;
>
> - Firstly, perform `removeClass()` from all radio button.
> - Then, `addClass()` only to the respective checked parent element.

```js
$('input:radio').change(function(){
  
   $('input:radio[name=' + this.name + ']').parent().removeClass('selected'); //remove class "selected" from all radio button with respective name
   $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); //add "selected" class only to the checked radio button
  
 });
```

```css
input[type="radio"] + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #fff5f5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey">
  <label for="huey">Huey</label>
</div>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
  <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
</div>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  <label for="louie">Louie</label>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Indeed, there's no reason for the `if($(this).is(':checked')) {` either. It will always be `true` for radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSeliger. Selector modified.

Comment: Could be simplified by removing *all* then adding to `this` - rather than add to `this` then remove from all except this

Comment: Code logic simplified and added code comment. Thanx @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

First remove all classes of parents, then add class to parent of selected one.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
  });
 $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #fff5f5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
  <label for="huey">Huey</label>
</div>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
  <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
</div>

<div class="">
  <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  <label for="louie">Louie</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it with only css

```css
input[type="radio"] ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  background-color: #fff5f5;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please include OPs html (or amended to ft your solution if needed) - in a snippet so that we can see this working

Answer (score 0):

This is a  *"fat free, valid HTML and CSS only"* variant with a slightly improved semantic structure ...

```css
.radio-group label,
.radio-group .content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.radio-group label {
  cursor: pointer;
} 
.radio-group label:hover {
  background-color: #fffbfb;
}
.radio-group .content {
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 1.3em 8px 8px 24px;
  margin: -1.3em 0 0 0;
}
.radio-group .label,
.radio-group [type="radio"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.radio-group [type="radio"] {
  top: 1px;
}
.radio-group [type="radio"]:checked ~ span {
  color: red;
}
.radio-group [type="radio"]:checked ~ .content {
  background-color: #fff5f5;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="radio-group">
  <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="drone" value="huey"/>
    <span class="label">Huey</span>
    <span class="content">... more phrasing content ...</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="drone" value="dewey"/>
    <span class="label">Dewey</span>
    <span class="content">... more phrasing content ...</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="drone" value="louie"/>
    <span class="label">Louie</span>
    <span class="content">... more phrasing content ...</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```js
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    $('input:radio').parent().removeClass('selected');  // Remove the class from every element
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');   // Add calss to the clicked element
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #fff5f5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="">
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey"
           checked />
    <label for="huey">Huey</label>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey" />
    <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie" />
    <label for="louie">Louie</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).